# background-image transition workaround

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to apply transition *"background-image"* on object hover and I found out that only Chrome supports this feature. Is there any workaround for this issue?

I'm using SVG as background if that makes any change.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Add some code @kannan

Comment: [**This**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css) is important to refer

Answer (score 1):

The clean way to deal with it is to use `:after` pseudo element.

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Logesh_RSR/zpa9Lxyd/)

For Example:-

```
a:hover:after {
    content: url(https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png); /* no need for qoutes */
    display: block;
}
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Logesh_RSR/zpa9Lxyd/)

Comment: Your post will look much better if you remove all those exclamation marks ... they add to much noise in it

Answer (score 0):

Refer: "[SVG is supported in Firefox?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css)".
CSS for SVG backround Transition:

```
.test:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><circle cx='5' cy='5' r='5' /></svg>");
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

.test:after {
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><circle cx='20' cy='20' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Working Snippet:**

```css
.test
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.test:before, .test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.test:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><circle cx='5' cy='5' r='5' /></svg>");
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

.test:after {
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><circle cx='20' cy='20' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.test:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  
</div>
```

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uheeswap/20/)